# Debezium connector for SQL Server and want to do the filteration at debezium layer

Tags: debezium

We are using debezium connector for SQL Server and want to do the filterating at debezium layer itself so that we can selectively pass the data onto a kafka topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this documentation: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html

Probably you will need something like this:

```
"transforms": "filter",
"transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter",
"transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy",
"transforms.filter.condition": "value.op == \"c\""
```